# GIMP 2.10 Drop Shadow are in separate layer - how to achieve like in GIMP 2.8

Tags: gimp

I am trying to use GIMP 2.10 like I used the previous version but am running into problems.  I been using GIMP since 2007.

The latest is that when I use Drop Shadow (under filters), the shadow is put right on the same layer as the picture I want to shadow rather than on a separate layer beneath it so I can play around with the shadow effect.

Any help will be appreciated!

Carol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old version is still available as `Filters>Light and shadow>Drop shadow (legacy)`.

IMHO not worth the effort, because it's not too interactive, the effect is a bit of hit or miss. A drop shadow is easy to do manually:

- On layer object: Layer>Transparency> Alpha to selection
- Add a layer, fill the selection with the shadow color
- Move the layer under the object
- Apply Gaussian blur (which is interactive)
- You can also shift the shadow layer a bit, and reduce its opacity.

Comment: Thanks so much xenoid!  I will try to find the legacy, otherwise I'll do it manually.  A bit time consuming compared to how it used to be!!  Oh well...progress!  (?)

Comment: Found it right away!  Thanks so much!  LOVE it!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer then...

Comment: Newbie stupid mistake - didn't know I was supposed to do that...DUH!   DONE!